# Check if page is indexed PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I want to check if a page has the meta tag noindex or is set to noindex at all. I was looking at parsing and checking for the keyword noindex within the  section, but I wouldn't have a clue where to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can get html source code from a page you can use PHP: DOMXpath to get certain element value you want. in this is <meta name="robots">. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Could use file_get_contents, run a search for the meta tag and get the value

Comment: I'm using a form on the previous page to enter a URL and then the content of whether the page is indexed or not on that page. I don't think any of these will work?

Comment: @clearshot66 has proposed that can work. Try to implement it and then see the result. Refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp) for better understanding.